# Get HTML element using jQuery

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

I have some DIVs with ID  "div1", "div2" ... "divx". I want to perform an operation on them. Is there any way to get the element ID .contains "div". Any other idea?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the [**starts with selector**](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

```
$("div[id^='div']")
```

The above will grab all divs that have an `id` attribute that begins with the letters `div`.

[**jsFiddle example** that makes all divs with id `div...` invisible.](http://jsfiddle.net/qXLpv/)

---

Here's how to handle the trickier case if you want to match `div` followed by a number but not `div` followed by something else. So `div1` would match, but `divx` would not.

In this case we use [**filter()**](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) with a function. The function should return true for when we want a match and false for when we do not. [match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_javascript_1.5_reference:objects:string:match) and a regex is great for this (you can use `[0-9]` to represent a digit in a regex or the simpler `[\d]`):

```
$("div").filter(function() {
    return $(this).attr("id").match(/^div[\d]+$/)
})
```

[attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) returns the value of the specified attribute, in this case `id`.

[**jsFiddle example** that makes all `div` followed by number disappear, but not `div` followed by other things.](http://jsfiddle.net/ekLKZ/)

Comment: While Peter's excellent answer's are totally correct, the *best* thing to do is add a class of "mydivs" or whatever (in the HTML) to all these divs so you can select them by class. That's why classes exist, to group like items. :)

Answer (score 7):

You could use this (I haven't tested it though):

```
jQuery("div[id^='div']")
```

This will get all `div` elements that have an `id` beginning with "div".

If you wanted all the `div` elements that have an `id` **containing** "div", then you could use this:

```
jQuery("div[id*='div']")
```

Answer (score 2):

Using ID's like div1, div2, div3 is a bad practice.  It's like naming your classes "black-bold-12px" and then assigning those styles to that class.  It misses the point on semantics.

The right way for doing this would be using a class for all of them.

Elements can be of more than one class, using a space as separator:

```
<div class="something usethis">...</div>
<div class="usethis something_else">...</div>
<div class="usethis">...</div>
<div class="something anotherclass usethis" id="someId">...</div>

<script>
  $(".usethis").html("New contents for all of them!");
</script>
```

Comment: The other answers answer the question, but this is the RIGHT answer

Comment: If you have a series of posts, having IDs like `post-1`, `post-23` etc. where the number is a unique universal post identifier seems perfectly legitimate and semantically informative... But yeah, it's certainly easier to work with well thought out classes when possible. ---- However, speaking of semantically well formed pages, external Javascript is superior to using the <script> tag ;)

Comment: @Peter  Yes, that's what I do if I need to identify every single one of them.  Anyway, if you think about it, having IDs like "post-1" is not the same as havig IDs like "div-1"... 
Still, when refering to them as a group it's better to use a class.

Comment: Just to be clear, I completely agree with you, and you make a great point overall.